# I am trying to create a table valued sql server function Func1(value) which returns data in comma separated values

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am trying to create a table valued sql server function "PatientId" which returns data in comma separated values as well as separated columns (both the ways).

For example

Table: table

|ID|PhaId
|1 | 100
|2| 200
|3|300
|4|400

the output shoud be..

|Id|PhaId| PhaId1| PhaId2|PhaId3
    |1 | 100 | | 200 |  300 | 400 |

we have a query for

select "Id",string_agg("PhaId"::text, ',') as "Pharmacy"
from "table"
where "Id" = 7
group by "Id";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a `xml path` construct in Postgres. Simply use `string_agg()`

```
select "PatientId",
       string_agg("PharmacyId"::text, ',')
from "PatientPharmacyXRef"
where "PatientId" = 1
group by "PatientId";
```

Additionally: the string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+` (but you don't need it here anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your help.... how can i convert result into separate columns... like (if result is 100,200,300,400) the out put is |ID|Value|  Value1| Value2|Value3
|1 | 100 | 200|300|400

Comment: @AmarAnugu: now you are changing the question. Please search for the tags `postgresql` and `pivot`